# Why are there no nodes under /controller znode while Kafka cluster is running?

Tags: apache-kafka

Output from the zookepeer client:

```
[zk: s1:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /brokers/ids
[1, 2, 3]
[zk: s1:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /controller
[]
```

There are 3 kafka brokers in the cluster, so why I can't find the controller in the /controller znode as well?

Another question is how can I know which master election used by kafka, ZooKeeper master election or Kafka master election? Is the master election in kafka to elect the master kafka broker? So what's the leader election? Is it to elect the leader partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking very general questions about how Kafka was designed.  For this, there's no better place to look than the official Kafka documentation:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#impl_zookeeper

The official controller explanation, from the docs (my highlights):

> It is also important to optimize the leadership election process as
>   that is the critical window of unavailability. A naive implementation
>   of leader election would end up running an election per partition for
>   all partitions a node hosted when that node failed. Instead, we elect
>   one of the brokers as the "controller". **This controller detects
>   failures at the broker level and is responsible for changing the
>   leader of all affected partitions in a failed broker.** The result is
>   that we are able to batch together many of the required leadership
>   change notifications which makes the election process far cheaper and
>   faster for a large number of partitions. **If the controller fails, one
>   of the surviving brokers will become the new controller.**

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_replicamanagment

So, the **controller** is the broker that is responsible for monitoring the leaders of each of the topic/partitions. If one or more of those leader topic/partitions becomes unavailable, the controller then runs **leader elections**, and appoints the new leader for each of those topic/partitions, so that clients (both consumers and producers) can consume/produce there.

The reason why you can't see anything under `/controller` is because you're assuming it's a "directory", when in reality it's a znode with information.  You need to issue a `get /controller` command to see the output. You should see something like this:

```
[zk: s1:2181(CONNECTED) 1] get /controller
{"version":1,"brokerid":100,"timestamp":"1506197069724"}
cZxid = 0xf9
ctime = Sat Sep 23 22:04:29 CEST 2017
mZxid = 0xf9
mtime = Sat Sep 23 22:04:29 CEST 2017
pZxid = 0xf9
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x15eaa3a4fdd000d
dataLength = 56
numChildren = 0
```